# Date conversion issue with objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Weird issue I'm having, if I do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy EEEE 'at' h:mm a"];
NSString *originalDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"In Date: %@",originalDate);
NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:originalDate];
NSLog(@"Out Date: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

I get this output:

```
In Date: April 30, 2013 Tuesday at 2:42 PM
Out Date: December 28, 1999 Tuesday at 2:42 PM
```

Why am I getting different dates after converting it to string and back using the same formatter? Is there a way to get this conversion to work properly?

Comment: Are you sure that's your real code? Here it displays `In Date: April 30, 2013 Tuesday at 2:57 PM` / `Out Date: April 30, 2013 Tuesday at 2:57 PM` (EDIT: rmaddy points out that this is a bug in a specific version of iOS; I tested under OS X so it's no surprise I got a different result)

Comment: @Tommy Did you test this under iOS 5 or 6?

Comment: I see the issue in a Cocoa CLI program

Comment: @rmaddy OS X v10.7.5 — this wasn't tagged as an iOS question at the time so I just leapt into CodeRunner.

Comment: @Tommy I added the iOS tag after but it now appears that this is an identical problem under both iOS 6 and OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS 6. `NSDateFormatter` can't properly parse date formats that have the weekday name anywhere besides the start of the string. I submitted a bug report for this a while ago. Still waiting for a fix.

The same format will work under iOS 5.

Update: Based on the test by vikingosegundo I update my own iOS tests. This appears to be the same issues as under OS X. It's not a simple matter of the weekday format being at the start, it is a bug if the weekday format appears after the year format.

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought I was going crazy. I changed the "day name" to the beginning and it worked like a charm!

Comment: This drove me crazy too until I realized it was a bug in iOS 6.

Comment: I found slightly different symptoms on Mac OS X. It seems as if the day name specifier needs to be left of the year specifier.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I just updated my own iOS tests. It is the same problem with iOS as OS X. As long as the weekday format is before the year format, it all works fine.

Comment: I updated my bug report with Apple to refine the scope of this issue and to mention that it is also an issue under OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this issue in a Cocoa command line program

Working formats

- `@"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a"`
- `@"MMMM EEEE d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a"`
- `@"MMMM d EEEE, yyyy 'at' h:mm a"`

Not working (*same symptoms as reported by OP*)

- `@"MMMM d, yyyy EEEE 'at' h:mm a"`
- `@"MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a EEEE"`

So the `EEEE` day name specifier needs to be left of the year specifier.
The bug also exists in Cocoa on Mac OS X 10.8.3

---

for further testing for copy and pasting:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy 'at' h:mm a EEEE"];
        NSString *originalDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSLog(@"In Date: %@",originalDate);
        NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:originalDate];
        NSLog(@"Out Date: %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of OS X are you seeing the issue. From Tommy's comment it appears to work fine with 10.7.5.

Comment: The copy and paste works fine under OS X v10.7.5; I guess whatever was updated and broken for iOS 6 then migrated into 10.8? EDIT: I should add, in case it makes any difference, I'm in PST but with the UK region format (including the 24-hour clock). So if there's some locale-specific component to Apple's bug then I may somehow be avoiding it. I notice the sample code doesn't set the locale to en_US_POSIX.

Comment: 10.8.3 added it to the answer.

Comment: Setting locale to en_US_POSIX does not change anything